# incrementing maven version through jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm trying to increment my pom version through Jenkins, but am facing many issues with the script element of the Jenkins declarative pipeline.
My goal is:

1. Jenkins pulls code from SCM
2. Run maven plugins
3. Increment version of application in the pom
4. Merge the new pom back into the SCM

I've managed to remove '-SNAPSHOT' from the version, and I've stored the version (e.g 1.0.0) in a variable within the script element of the pipeline. I am unable to then use that variable to be able tin increment it.

`pipeline {
    agent any
    tools { 
        maven 'maven'
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Git checkout branch') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'branch', credentialsId: '****', url: 'https://projectRepo'
            }
        }
        stage ('Increment snapshot') {
            steps {
                dir('directory') {
                    //Remove snapshot from version in pom
                    sh 'mvn versions:set -DremoveSnapshot'
                    script {
                        //Get the version and assign to variable 'version'
                        version = '$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)'
                    }
                    //content of version can only be accessed by ${version}
                    sh "echo ${version}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

My aim is to get the version within the script tags, then perform a split like this .split("\."), then increment the last number, then, when I do a release, I'll use the maven flag to update the pom with the new version, plus add -SNAPSHOT to the end of the version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the build-helper-maven-plugin, you can parse the version into its components:

https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html

This offers not only elements like `majorVersion` and `minorVersion`, but also `nextMajorVersion`, `nextMinorVersion` etc.

Comment: Thank you. The following mvn command allowed me to increment the incremental version, and allows me to add SNAPHSOT/TEST/RELEASE onto the end of the version:
`mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT versions:commit`

Comment: For info, the above maven command works fine in a CLI, but the syntax will need to be changed for it to work in a Jenkins declarative pipeline. Here is the stage and step showing how to use it in the Jenkins pipeline:
`stage ('Increment snapshot') {
            steps {
                dir('PiersDemo') {
                   sh "mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion='\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT' versions:commit"
                }
            }
        }`